# Does FlameRobin have problems with the insertion of umlauts?

Tags: utf-8, firebird, flamerobin

I have a table with a field

> VALCONTENT BLOB SUB_TYPE TEXT SEGMENT SIZE 80

When I browse the table, right click on an entry, select "Edit blob" the content is shown.

If I enter "normal" test ("Hello world"), I can click "Save" and things work.

If I use umlauts ("Hällö Wörld"), I get an error message:

> IBPP::SQLExcetption, Contenten: Statement: Execure (Update MyTable set
> foo= ? where ..." Message isc_dsql_execute2 failed, -303, incompatible
> column, malformed string

Am I doing something wrong or is FlameRobin not able to handle UTF8?

I am using Firebird 4.0 64bit, FlameRobin 0.9.3 Unicode x64 (all just downloaded).
Extracting the DDL with "iSQL -o" shows in the first line

> /* CREATE DATABASE 'E:\foo.fdb' PAGE_SIZE 16384 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET
> UTF8; */

Comment: What is the character set of the column? Also, which version of FlameRobin and which version of Firebird are you using?

Comment: I added data to the post above. The table or doesn't show different charset-definitions as far as I see (I posted the DDE of the table above)

Comment: What is connection charset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue (with blob character set UTF8 and connection character set UTF8), which suggests this is a bug in FlameRobin. I recommend reporting it on https://github.com/mariuz/flamerobin/issues. I'm not sure what the problem is. Updating does seem to work fine when using connection character set WIN1252.

Consider using a different tool, maybe DBeaver, or IBExpert, etc.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/mariuz/flamerobin/issues/237